# different dtype for addData method

Tags: psychopy

I'm trying to add a timestamp in my code using the TrialHandler.addData() methode. However, the precision of the underlying array makes it impossible to get the exact value I need.

```
print(core.getAbsTime())    
hand.addData('time', core.getAbsTime())
print(hand.data['time'])
#prints 1410454966
#       [[1410454912.0] ...
```

Is there a way to change the underlying type to be able to acheive the needed precision?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to use `core.getAbsTime()` which returns the unix timestamp. It is not mean for timing in experiments. For timing of events in the experiments use

```
myClock = core.Clock()
myClock.reset()  # start timing
# do something here
elapsedTime = myClock.getTime()  # yay
```

... which returns the time in microseconds. Se the documentation for `core.Clock` and `core.getAbsTime()` in [psychopy.core](http://www.psychopy.org/api/core.html) documentation and in the Coder demos.

If you want the absolute time (year, hour, minutes etc.), see the [time](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) python module or search Google for similar modules and methods.

Comment: I do not use it for timing in a experiment, but to synchronise loosely with other logs.

Comment: Ok, google e.g. "python time milliseconds since epoch" to find various answers. Most point to ``time.time()``.